# How to write if command with arguments

Tags: bash

I've an question, how to use *if *or *case * statements to do below command :

command.sh --value string ?

I tried :

```
case "$1" in
   [--value ])
   echo "You choose value"
   ;;
   *)
   echo "plz chs diff one"
   ;;
esac
```

But it is not what I want to achieve.
I want to run command.sh --value string , where string is the first argument.

Comment: If `$1` is `value` they check `$2` and use it.

Comment: did you try `case "$1" in --value ) do_something ;; * ) echo unexpected option; exit 1 ;; esac` ? You may need `"--value"` (`[` `]` sq brackets have a different "meaning" in shell syntax which apply in `case` statements, search for info on "shell character class(es)") . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`getopts` is a tool that can be used to parse arguments

```
usage() {
  echo "Usage: $0 [-v]" 1>&2
  }
  exit_abnormal() {
    usage
exit 1
}
while getopts "v" arg; do
        case $arg in
        v) USE_VALUE='true' ;;
        ?)
          echo "Invalid option: -${OPTARG}."
          echo
          usage
            ;;
        esac
done

shift

if [[ $USE_VALUE == "true" ]]; then
  ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if [ "$1" = "--value" ]; then
   echo "You choose value $2"
else
   echo "plz chs diff one"
fi
```